# What IP address should be bound to a server application's socket?

Tags: c, sockets, server

I've just recently started playing around with sockets in C. Today I've been trying to write a server application to run on an old laptop of mine, just to experiment a bit. 
I'd like for the server's services to be accessible from remote hosts and I'm confused about which IP address the server's socket should be bound to: is there an IP address that uniquely identifies my machine online or am I missing a step (or possibly many more) here?

```
struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
memset(&serverAddress, 0, sizeof(serverAddress));

serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(8080);

if(bind(serverSocketDescriptor, (struct sockaddr*) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) {

    printf("bind() failed\n");
    closesocket(serverSocketDescriptor);
    WSACleanup();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to bind to `INADDR_ANY`, which translates to 0.0.0.0.

```
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

Binding to this address means the socket is bound to all local addresses, including localhost and any external IPs the host may have.

Comment: I see. But what address should the client application connect to then?

Comment: @Gian The client, assuming it's on another host, connects to the external IP address.  Local clients can use that or connect to localhost.

Comment: What do you mean by "external IP address"? I tried connecting to the address provided by my ISP but it just keeps failing to connect. How can I get the right address for the client to connect to?

Comment: @Gian The IP from your ISP is typically assigned to your router.  Your PC has its own IP address.  Assuming the other machine is on the same internal network, that's the IP you want to use.  You can't use the IP from your ISP unless you set up port forwarding on the router.

Comment: I already knew how to connect multiple hosts connected to the same network. I'd like for hosts outside of my network to be able to connect to this server, though (that's what I meant in the original post). Is it something not as easy to do? Should I look into port forwarding for this?

Comment: @Gian You need to look at your router's configuration.  There should be a setting for any traffic coming in on a particular port to be forwarded to a particular IP/port on the inside.

Comment: I finally got it. Great! I was finally able to make it work. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest reading: [server code sequence](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-server-client-implementation-in-c/)

```
//  int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
sock_t sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if( sock < 0 )
{
    perror( "socket failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// if wanting to set any socket options (setsockopt())
// this is the place to do so

struct sockaddr_in server;
memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));

server.sin_family      = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( INADDR_ANY ); 
server.sin_port        = htons(8080);  


if( bind( sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server) ) ) 
{
    perror( "bind() failed" );
    close( sock );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

if( listen(sock, 5) )
{
    perror( "listen failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

struct sockaddr_in client;
size_t len = sizeof( client ); 

while(1)
{
    sock_t clientSock = accept(sock, &client, &len); 
    if( clientSock <  0 )
    {
        perror( "accept failed" );
        continue;
    }

    // handle client connection
    close( clientSock );
}


close( sock );
```

Note: for long term consistency, the computer running this code needs to have a 'static' IP address, not a 'dynamic' IP address.